# Site is not loading and showing Directory listing on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-10

I have deployed MVC 5 website on IIS but its not loading website and showing directory listing
I am using .Net Framework 4.8 and MVC 5 here is my web.config and OS is Window 10

```
<system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <!-- required for apple-app-site-association: -->
            <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/json" />
        </staticContent>

        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <!-- 100MB -->
                <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <handlers>
            <!-- This seems to force it to NOT handle files under /Course/* ?! -->
            <!-- TODO Research this nonsense -->
            <remove name="StaticFileHandler" />
            <add name="StaticFileHandler" path="/Course/*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <clear />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
```

I have applied below solution but still not working

1. Enabled/Disabled directory browsing
2. User below module

Comment: Maybe no routes are matching? The config above shows an enabled directory browsing. If disabling it still “shows the listing”, then the correct (or combined) config is not used as expected. I would start with directory browsing disable and *leave/show* it disabled — and re-verify the IIS behavior — for the question. (This is a crucial debugging detail and will ensure the question starts with a reduced issue scope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS 6.0 suddenly shows directory listing instead of MVC 3 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723763/iis-6-0-suddenly-shows-directory-listing-instead-of-mvc-3-app)

Comment: Thanks everyone I have fixed this issue, it's because of Temporary files of global.aspx so i have removed that and re deployed its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Run this command for install mvc application

`install-windowsfeature web-asp-net45`